Shadow casting/lighting artifacts on flatshaded mesh
I am procedurally generating chunks using the marching cubes algorithm. I started out by using shared vertices among triangles, but quickly chose to use 3 unique vertices per triangle due to face normals. I currently get the flat shaded look I want, but I simply can't get the shadows to work properly (as you can see in the first picture). I calculate the normals for each vertex as you can see in picture 2. I simply calculate each vertex normal by calculating the face normal for the triangle the vertex belongs to. I'm currently just using the default material for the mesh.
Current situation


Normals calculation


I am looking for similar shadows as in Astroneer
Shadows in Astroneer

Any help or advise is appreciated.

I can't get. Whats wrong with shadows? Low resolution shadowmap?
